# Delete VBA module

Tags: vba, ms-access, corrupt

I was deleting an Access Object (a report) and Access crashed during the delete.

The object no longer exists in Access, but its module still shows up in VBA like a ghost.

If I click on it, I get a FILE NOT FOUND error.

If I try to compact & repair or compile the database, I get a FILE NOT FOUND error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential option is to create a new database file, and import all of the content from the old database file. that will clear out the funky ghost stuff.

Comment: Thank you, KySoto!

Comment: I have had this EXACT thing happen to me. it was not fun.

Answer (score 1):

you write you tried compile already and it did not work.

Did you try decompile first though?

First of all make a backup copy (but am sure you already did that :) )

With Access and your access file closed type from the command prompt:
C:\yourOfficeInstallPath\MSACCESS.EXE /decompile

Access will start. Click File > Open and select the database you want to decompile
Open any module and click Debug > Compile

Then save your file and close.

Open again your file and compact it.

Let me know if it solved it.